# internal error in apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, 500-error, logging

I have upgrade php version on my server.this causes logging many deprecated errors in error_log file of apache.

these days i get many internal error on page requests and very very high rate in load average of server.

will these floody logging cause apache to get out of service?

my server os is debian.

Answer (score 1):

A misconfigured php / or broken php is source of endless headche for httpd administrators. Please update your code to conform the new php version specs. That way logging of useless error in logs will stop and there by reducing the pressure on httpd. If it logging too much of error in log and is starting to serve a moderate traffic and it will start to crash, mainly b'cos in a matter of few hours or mintues (depending upon the traffic) the logs would have grown enourmously big. there by making httpd task of loggin difficult. If you have set log rotating then you only gain little time, but doent solve the real problem. The filesysytem would fill up quicky and thus making the httpd logging feature to be difficult leading to server crash b'cso of lack of space in host machine. Then even ssh into the box might become a issue and then you have to use console logging to solve this. This will be further mulitpled problem when the host is co shared with other application and other application will start bnehaving stranegly and finally crash when the httpd about to fail due lack of space. i am not talking about other web based app on httpd . instead other non web app running in that same host, as Every process needs the space to funciton. That where logrotate come in handy. once found the extend and nature of problem and if the dev is unwilling to change code to fix this. then we can instruct logrotate ultility to automatically archive roated logs and set time for archived logs to be deleted. Cool utility isnt it.

Hope that helps.